# Swift 3: Saving login information

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, swift3, xcode8.2

I'm working on a simple webview app in Xcode 8.2.1.

Yes, I know. There's a newer version available, but the Mac I have assigned won't update to High Sierra. I'm stuck with El Capitan. So, I've followed some simple tutorials and I've come to develop a simple app that will load my website.
The app itself works, but there's a slight *big* issue: when the users close the app, the cookies will destroy themselves and the user will have to login *again.*
I don't want to make them login again if they accidentally close the app or something like that.
How can I do this? I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/65aae0/is_there_a_way_to_autoenable_cookies_inside_of_a/) that I could use

```
@UIApplicationMain 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate 
    {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always
        return true
    }
```

but, unfortunately it won't work and the login information will clear after the app is closed.

This is `ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if myWebView.canGoBack{
            myWebView.goBack()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        myWebView.reload()
    }

    @IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if myWebView.canGoForward{
            myWebView.goForward()
        }
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myURL")!))

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

And this is `AppDelegate.swift`

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func saveCookies() {
        guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else {
            return
        }
        let array = cookies.flatMap { (cookie) -> [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]? in
            cookie.properties
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "cookies")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func loadCookies() {
        guard let cookies = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cookies") as? [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]] else {
            return
        }
        cookies.forEach { (cookie) in
            guard let cookie = HTTPCookie.init(properties: cookie) else {
                return
            }
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }

}
```

This app won't be published on the appstore and it's intended just for three users in my company. This is why I decided to do a simple thing and not something big-scaled.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, if it's just a simple webview app, why not just get them to browse directly to the website in question? Then their browser can save the details for them?

Comment: Orders from my boss. He wants it to work that way. * sighs * That's what I suggested in the first place.

Comment: In that case, are you 100% sure that the website on it's own does persist the cookie as well? Or does that also expire on browser close? The issue could be with the cookie times there rather than the iOS app

Comment: 100% sure. I did the same thing for Android, and I don't have problems with it.

Comment: Note: if you simply press the home button and open the app again, it's cool. The problem comes when you close the app using the task manager, and when you delete it from your recent apps. I don't have this issue in the Android app. I can turn my phone off and still have the active session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to re-set the cookies.

```
NSData *cookiesdata = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MySavedCookies"];
if([cookiesdata length]) {
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookiesdata];
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;

    for (cookie in cookies) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```